# How to link two depended inputs of unknown size with variables

Tags: python, variables, input, interactive

This is my first python script. My data looks like this:

```
Position ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4 ind5 ind5 ind7 ind8
 0        C    A     C   A    A    A    A     A
 1        C    A     C   C    C    A    A     A
```

but it may vary in a number of columns and has thousands of rows.

My script which does what I need reads this file line by line and calculates the the frequency of A and C for combination of individuals (hereafter population) in every position (POS). For example freq of A at position 0 for population 1 (ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4); and freq of A at position 0 for population 2 (ind5, ind6, ind7, ind8), then the same for POS 1, 2, 3 ....

To do this I define combination of columns (populations) in my script by this code:

```
alleles1 = alleles[1:5]
alleles2 = alleles[5:]
```

but if I have more than 9 columns and different combination of columns, I need to modify alleles* and the rest of the script afterwards.

**I want to make my program more interactive, that a user defines number of populations and specifies which column correspond to which population.**

The code I have so far:

```
#ask for the number of populations
try:
    num_pop = int(raw_input("How many populations do you have? > "))
except ValueError:
    print "In is not an integer! \nThe program exits...\n "
#ask for individuals in population
ind_pop = {}
for i in range(num_pop):
    i += 1
    ind_input = str(raw_input("Type column numbers of population %i > " % i))
    ind_pop[i] = re.findall(r'[^,;\s]+', ind_input)
```

if I have 2 populations, where columns 3, 5, 6 is population 1, and columns 2, 5 is population 2. It works in this way:

```
> How many populations do you have? > 2
> Type column numbers of population 1 > 3, 5, 6  
> Type column numbers of population 2 > 2, 4
```

The input is stored in the dictionary.

```
{1: ['3', '5', '6'], 2: ['2', '4']}
```

**The question is how to proceed from this input to defining alleles. 
The output should be like this:**

```
allele1 =  [allele[3], allele[5], allele[6]]
allele2 =  [allele[2], allele[4]]
```

If it is necessary here are the main parts of the rest of the code:

```
with open('test_file.txt') as datafile:
  next(datafile)
  for line in datafile:
    words = line.split() #splits string into the list of words 
    chr_pos = words[0:2] #select column chromosome and position
    alleles = words[2:] # this and next separates alleles for populations

    alleles1 = alleles[0:4]
    alleles2 = alleles[4:8]
    alleles3 = alleles[8:12]
    alleles4 = alleles[12:16]

    counter1=collections.Counter(alleles1)
    counter2=collections.Counter(alleles1)
    counter3=collections.Counter(alleles1)
    counter4=collections.Counter(alleles1)
#### the rest of the code and some filters within the part above were spiked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to convert the column numbers to integers

```
    ind_pop[i] = [int(j) for j in re.findall(r'[^,;\s]+', ind_input)]
```

(I would also change your regular expression to `r'\d+'`)

Then instead of having `alleles1`, `alleles2` etc., have a master list or dictionary:

```
master = {i: [alleles[j] for j in vals] for i, vals in ind_pop.items()}
counters = {i: collections.Counter(al) for i, al in master.items()}
```

Then you can access `counters[i]` instead of `counter1` etc.

As a side note, you can probably simplify all of the above by making `ind_pop` into a list, using `append` instead of keeping the counter

Comment: Dear Felipe, thank you for r'\d+'
You are right about converting to integers. I did as you suggest.
A master list or dictionary does help a little but it does not do exactly what I wanted. I have already come up with the solution. I'll post it in answers.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output you're looking for,

```
allele1 =  [allele[3], allele[5], allele[6]]
allele2 =  [allele[2], allele[4]]
```

and you have this:

```
{1: ['3', '5', '6'], 2: ['2', '4']}
```

it's pretty simple from here.

```
for index in population_dict[1]:
    allele1.append(allele[index])
for index in population_dict[2]:
    allele2.append(allele[index])
```

Oh, if the indices are stored as strings, as they look like they are above, you'll need to make them ints first.  You could change the above to allele[int(index)], but it would be better to just make them into ints when you read them.

Comment: The problem is that 'population_dict' may vary depending on user input. I found the solution see below in answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions. Some of them were useful. I feel that I need to change the direction. I will continue working with a list of list:

```
pop_alleles = []
for key in ind_pop.keys():
  pop_alleles.append([alleles[el] for el in ind_pop[key]])
```